# how to write data on server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am making a registration page were user can register?
this is my code..............

```
-(IBAction)btn_log:(id)sender
    {

//NSString* username = nameInput.text;
//NSString* pass = passInput.text;

NSString* firstname = nameInput.text;
NSString* lastname = passInput.text;
NSString* bname = lastInput.text;


NSString *post = 
[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"fname=%@&lname=%@&email=%@",firstname,lastname,bname];

//NSString *post = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"fname=firstname&lname=lastname&email=bname];

NSData * postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSString * postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.yoursite.com/file.php"]]]; 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (conn) NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
  }
```

But it's not working so please can anyone suggest me where i am making mistake.

Comment: can you give more information as to why the request isn't working? there are so many different ways that the call could fail.

Comment: Look at NSURLConnection delegate documentation

Comment: I m abe to send hardcore data to database but when wanted to pass the data from my string to database but it is not going

Answer (score 1):

try in this way may be it will help you

Nsurl *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.yoursite.com/file.php"]]]; 
nsstring *body = [nsstring stringwithformat:@"%@,%@",nameinput,paasinput];
nsmutableurlrequest *request = [nsmutablerequest alloc]initwithurl:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request sethttpbody:[body dataysubgebcidubg:asciiiencoding allowlossyconversion : true]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (conn) NSLog(@"Connection Successful");

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Replace above line of your code with following line. Probably it will work.

```
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: I don't know about it because in my app i have shown activity indicator.